# Serve SSL certificate directly from PostFix / Dovecot to Thunderbird WITHOUT webserver

Tags: apache-http-server, thunderbird, postfix, dovecot, letsencrypt

**Webserver host:** web.example.nl

**Mailserver host:** mail.example.nl

**Mail user:** test@user.nl *(letsencrypt cert issued for this domain)*

I am trying to setup a new mailserver on mail.example.nl that doesn't use Apache or any other webserver functionality so that the mailserver remains 'clean'. For SSL certificates I use Letsencrypt DNS based validation and that works perfectly.

I created the first mail user in Virtualmin (test@user.nl) and even installed the SSL certificate in PostFix / DoveCot (for this specific host) with the Virtualmin UI.

But when I try to add the E-mail account in Thunderbird, then Thunderbird tries to get the certificate from the webserver on web.example.nl and not from my mailserver mail.example.nl. I am guessing this is because Thunderbird can't find any webserver on mail.example.nl so the it checks the root domain. *(so, I get a SSL mismatch error because the server on web.example.nl doesn't have a Certificate for mail.example.nl)*

**Now I wonder; Shouldn't it be possible to serve SSL certificates to Thunderbird directly from Dovecot or Postfix? Or do I always need a webserver for that?**

EDIT:
Here's the output of open_ssl:

***$: openssl s_client -showcerts -servername mail.user.nl -connect mail.user.nl:993***

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -servername mail.user.nl -connect mail.user.nl:993

depth=2 C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = mail.user.nl
verify return:1
CONNECTED(00000003)
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = mail.user.nl
   i:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Jan 19 14:11:02 2023 GMT; NotAfter: Apr 19 14:11:01 2023 GMT
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 1 s:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
   i:C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Sep  4 00:00:00 2020 GMT; NotAfter: Sep 15 16:00:00 2025 GMT
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
nLRbwHOoq7hHwg==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 2 s:C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
   i:O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 4096 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Jan 20 19:14:03 2021 GMT; NotAfter: Sep 30 18:14:03 2024 GMT
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=CN = mail.user.nl
issuer=C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 4599 bytes and written 408 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
DONE
```

Comment: Have you checked the configuration with OpenSSL or testssl.sh?

Comment: See my recent edit...

Comment: You are testing the wrong server (mail instead of mail1) and using the wrong port (143 instead of 993).

Comment: You were right with the port 993. Now I got a working SSL certificate back with the OpenSSL tester. (see edit). But, is was the right server. To clearify better: **I have two domains. mail.example.nl is the hostname of the mailserver, and mail.user.nl is a domain that points to the same IP adres.** My SSL certificate is issued for the user (mail.user.nl)

So, now i know that there is a working SSL certificate installed on the right server. But WHY does thunderbird think that it has to find the SSL at the webserver (web1.example.nl), and not at the mailserver (mail.example.nl)

Comment: Okay, I removed all records that were not pointing to the mailserver (so the autoconfig. subdomain and even the @ root domain), **and now it works!**
But, I need those domains that are pointing to the webserver! I think this is caused by a faulty autoconfig that thunderbird is even using for SSL when I manually configure the account. It would help a lot if there was a Autodiscover tester...